# sql profile option is disabled in EDB PEM TOOL

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

I am trying to activate sql profiler option in edb postgres.
i have completed below prerequisites.

-> installed sqlprofile rpm for edb

-> added     `shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/sql-profiler'`   in postgres.conf file

-> Ran the sql-profiler.sql file against the database ( it was successful)

-> Restarted the services:

However still the sql profile option is disabled in EDB PEM console.

Is there any way to run sql profile from postgres cli .

Answer (score 0):

If you have connected to the PEM server with the PEM client before configuring SQL Profiler, you must disconnect and reconnect with the server to enable SQL Profiler functionality.

Also make sure that you have executed sql-profiler.sql in postgres database in your enterprisedb DBMS, not in edb database.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue.
I was running the sql profiler script against edb database, But in PEM console, in server properties I have kept postgres as maintenance db.

So i have changed that to edb , and then connected to PEM server, sql profiler option was enabled.